# Is there a way to collect the first file attached to an item in a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a sharepoint list whose items are always created with a single attachment. Subsequently, any number of attachments may be added. A flow that works on this list sends emails to different people as appropriate. Most of these emails must have only the original attachment attached. The current solution is to impose a naming convention on the original attachment. The flow gathers the attachments and uses a conditional to select the attachment that matches the naming convention. It would be easier and more robust if the flow could select the attachment by date or order by which it was attached rather than by name.

Is there a way for Power Automate to select the attachment that was first attached to a single item in a sharepoint list?